# Jump to the end of agreement in Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard

How to jump to the end of software license agreement in the Terminal? I want to avoid hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to read line by line, I just want to jump to the end.

Answer (score 1):

If the license pager is `less`, try hitting capital `G`.